# VMware api get snapshot list with ids for a VM

Tags: vmware

I have a vm that has 2 snapshots, and I want to revert to any of those snapshots using vmware api.

I followed this instructions: https://code.vmware.com/forums/5098/vrealize-automation#576169

it works ok, but the problem it always revert to current snapshot, and I want to revert to any of 2 snapshots I have.

I think I should specify in the request payload the snapshot id, but I haven't found a way to get snapshot list with their id using api.

The more similar info about snapshot I found is with $SERVER_URI/catalog-service/api/consumer/resources/$INSTANCE_ID

but I get:

```
"key": "SNAPSHOT_LIST",
        "value": {
          "type": "multiple",
          "elementTypeId": "COMPLEX",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "complex",
              "componentTypeId": "com.vmware.csp.component.iaas.proxy.provider",
              "componentId": null,
              "classId": "dynamicops.api.model.SnapshotViewModel",
              "typeFilter": null,
              "values": {
                "entries": [
                  {
                    "key": "SNAPSHOT_IS_MEMORY",
                    "value": {
                      "type": "boolean",
                      "value": false
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "key": "SNAPSHOT_IS_CURRENT",
                    "value": {
                      "type": "boolean",
                      "value": false
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "key": "SNAPSHOT_CREATION_DATE",
                    "value": {
                      "type": "dateTime",
                      "value": "2019-09-05T20:30:06.540Z"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "key": "SNAPSHOT_DESC",
                    "value": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "value": ""
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "type": "complex",
              "componentTypeId": "com.vmware.csp.component.iaas.proxy.provider",
              "componentId": null,
              "classId": "dynamicops.api.model.SnapshotViewModel",
              "typeFilter": null,
              "values": {
                "entries": [
                  {
                    "key": "SNAPSHOT_IS_MEMORY",
                    "value": {
                      "type": "boolean",
                      "value": false
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "key": "SNAPSHOT_IS_CURRENT",
                    "value": {
                      "type": "boolean",
                      "value": true
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "key": "SNAPSHOT_CREATION_DATE",
                    "value": {
                      "type": "dateTime",
                      "value": "2019-09-09T17:45:58.870Z"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "key": "SNAPSHOT_DESC",
                    "value": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "value": "This is a Test snaposhot"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
```

This does not shows the snapshot id that I can use in the request payload.

Thanks for the help.